# Wordpress blank wp-admin and some pages are not working with www

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have moved an Wordpress from one server to another. The address remained the same, so nothing is changed in the URL structure. The steps followed are as described in [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) page.

However when I try to access the admin page (`www.mydomain.com/wp-admin`) I get a blank page. Also, the same happens to some pages on my site - but not all of them. Some are working some are not.

In my .htaccess I have the usual:

> ```
> # BEGIN WordPress
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
>
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
> </IfModule>
>
> # END WordPress
> ```

Under wp-admin folder, .htaccess file is empty.

After a lot of testing, I find out that when I access `http://mydomain.com/wp-admin` (without www) is loading the login page, but after entering the username and password I get another blank page (it basically redirects to `www.mydomain.com`).

I believe this is not a .htaccess, but something inside Wordpress. I have the correct URL and HOME setup in wp_config (also because the domain did not changed after moving to a different server).

Strange thing is that some pages are working, some don't. What could be the reason?

Comment: hows you took backup of your old website? through `admin->tools->import` / `export` or Manually>

Comment: @ jogesh_pi - Manually - I have copied all files and also database with phpmyadmin.

Comment: For example, I just found that www.mydomain.com/contact/ is not working, whereas a lot of other pages are working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the reason for this is a blank space left on wp-config.php file, which made WP crash (not sure why other pages were working though...).